# How to pass parameters to REST resource using Jersey 2.5

Tags: java, rest, embedded-jetty, jersey-2.0

I have a Java server which serves my clients (Not application server).

Now I'm interested to add REST support. I've initialized a Jetty server and created few REST resources.

My question is: **How can I pass parameters at the creation of the REST resources?**

Normally I would prefer in the constructor of each resource, but I don't control it.

I understand there is a way to inject dependencies. How to do it using Jersey 2.5??

Thank you!

Comment: I think it is much simpler to create REST server with Spring, look at this example http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/ This still uses Jersey, but requires a lot less code to create whole REST service.

Comment: I've already created REST service but I only need to pass parameters to every REST resource's constructor.

Comment: Show some code, then will be easier to help

Answer (score 1):

Define your Application

```
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {
  public MyApplication() {
    register(new FacadeBinder());
    register(JacksonFeature.class);
    register(MyEndpoint.class);
}
```

Configure injection

```
public class FacadeBinder extends AbstractBinder {

  @Override
  protected void configure() {
    bind(MyManager.class).to(MyManager.class);
  }
}
```

Inject configured classes in your endpoint

```
@Path("/jersey")
public class MyEndpoint {
  @Inject
  MyManager myManager;
  ...
}
```

Comment: This almost looks perfect except that in the 'FacadeBinder' I pass the .class of my custom class instead of creating an instance and passing arguments in constructor.

Comment: You should reconsider programming practice to avoid operator **new** in business code. Consider use of factory to customize instance creation instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand what do you mean with dependencies.

You should check this: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d0e1810

Comment: I'm familiar with guide. but still it doesn't clear to me how to accomplish what I need.

Comment: All I need it a way to pass a class instance into REST resources.

Comment: I think you could use @BeanParam annotation

Answer (score 0):

Another option besides using dependency injection is to instantiate and register the REST endpoint yourself.  Jersey allows you to do this in a very similar fashion as dependency injection as shown in Dymtro's example.  Borrowing liberally from Dymtro, define your endpoint:

```
@Path("/jersey")
public class MyEndpoint {
    private MyManager myManager;
    public MyEndpoint(MyManager myManager) {
        this.myManager = myManager;
    }
    ....
}
```

Define your application:

```
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {
    public MyApplication(MyManager myManager) {
        register(JacksonFeature.class);
        register(new MyEndpoint(myManager));
        ....
    }
}
```